# Python plot multiple circle on grid with legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations, grid, subplot

I want to plot on a grid of N by M, circles of various color and same size. On a x,y location, can be a circle or nothing.

I would like to have a x label for each column (that would be here a week), and an ylabel (that would be here a subject).

For now, I found a way to plot the circles using subplots, but I can't manage to had the text nor the grid.

Here is my code to draw the circles:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Wedge
from plotly.graph_objs import *
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

def dual_half_circle(center, radius, angle=0, ax=None, colors=('w','k'), **kwargs):
    """
    Add two half circles to the axes *ax* (or the current axes) with the 
    specified facecolors *colors* rotated at *angle* (in degrees).
    """
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    kwargs.update(transform=ax.transAxes, clip_on=False)
    theta1, theta2 = angle, angle + 180
    w1 = Wedge(center, radius, theta1, theta2, fc=colors[0], **kwargs)
    w2 = Wedge(center, radius, theta2, theta1, fc=colors[1], **kwargs)
    for wedge in [w1, w2]:
        ax.add_artist(wedge)
    return [w1, w2]
```

Here is a code to display everything (I removed the color conditions):

```
DF = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([True, False], size = (15, 10)))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for ii in range(0,DF.shape[1]):    
    for jj in range(0,DF.shape[0]):
        if DF[ii][jj]:
            dual_half_circle((ii, -1*jj), radius=0.3, colors=('b','g'), angle=90, ax=ax)
            ax.axis('equal')

for ii in range(0,DF.shape[1]):       
    plt.annotate(xy= (ii, 1), s= 'W'+str(ii), fontsize = 100, verticalalignment='center', horizontalalignment='center')

for jj in range(0,DF.shape[0]):
    plt.annotate(xy =(-1, -1*jj),s= 'subj '+str(jj), fontsize = 100, verticalalignment='center', horizontalalignment='center')

plt.show()
```

And here is the result, where I don't have the annotation nor the grid

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmMUf.png)

Should I change from subplot to classical plot to be able to add what I want?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is there any reason not to show a [mcve] here? What do you mean by grid? Is it the one you get with `plt.grid()`, if not, explain what you mean. Do you get the desired result when removing the line `plt.axis("off")`?

Comment: Sorry, I modified the post...
    `plt.axis("off")` allow to remove the small grid top left of the plot, that is not a grid that I would like.
I would prefer have some horizontal and vertical lines between the subplot, but not a x,y grid with axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. (I still don't understand the thing with the grid, so I left that out)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Wedge
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def dual_half_circle(center, radius, angle=0, ax=None, colors=('w','k'), **kwargs):
    """
    Add two half circles to the axes *ax* (or the current axes) with the 
    specified facecolors *colors* rotated at *angle* (in degrees).
    """
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    theta1, theta2 = angle, angle + 180
    w1 = Wedge(center, radius, theta1, theta2, fc=colors[0], **kwargs)
    w2 = Wedge(center, radius, theta2, theta1, fc=colors[1], **kwargs)
    for wedge in [w1, w2]:
        ax.add_artist(wedge)
    return [w1, w2]

DF = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([True, False], size = (15, 10)))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,13))
for ii in range(0,DF.shape[1]):    
    for jj in range(0,DF.shape[0]):
        if DF[ii][jj]:
            dual_half_circle((ii, -1*jj), radius=0.3, colors=('b','g'), angle=90, ax=ax)
            ax.axis('equal')

for ii in range(0,DF.shape[1]):       
    plt.annotate(xy= (ii, 1), s= 'W'+str(ii), fontsize = 10, verticalalignment='center', horizontalalignment='center')

for jj in range(0,DF.shape[0]):
    plt.annotate(xy =(-1, -1*jj),s= 'subj '+str(jj), fontsize =10, verticalalignment='center', horizontalalignment='right')

ax.set_xlim(-1,10)
ax.set_ylim(-15,3)
plt.axis("off")
plt.plot([-1,10], [-15,3], alpha=0)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much that is working perfectly.
Just to understand, why did you put the `figsize=(8,13)`? Is there something specific with these values?

And also the grid I talk is just a way to have all the circle in some kind of tabular for a better reading.

Comment: If your array to plot has shape `(y,x)` (`(15, 10)` here), then choosing the figure size `figsize = (w, h)`, where `w/x ~= h/y` seems natural to me. But any figure size would work.

Comment: And to conclude with the idea of grid, I solved it using segments:
` for ii in range(0,DF.shape[1]-1): plt.plot([ii+0.5, ii+0.5], [-1*(DF.shape[0]-0.5), 0.5], color='k', linestyle='dotted', linewidth=grid_width)`
 and 
`for jj in range(1,DF.shape[0]): plt.plot([-0.5, DF.shape[1]-0.5], [-1*jj+0.5, -1*jj+0.5], color='k', linestyle='dotted', linewidth=grid_width)`